# LibGDX: Draw one font multiple times with different text

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I am trying to make it so multiple words (generated at random) appear at the top of the screen and fall to the bottom. This means that the font is drawn multiple times on the screen. But whenever a new word appears, it should change that particular one to something different than the previous word. This works, but for some reason it also changes the first word that appeared.

Here's my code:

PlayState class:

```
public class PlayState extends State {

// TODO: add a background

private BitmapFont font;
private Word word;

public PlayState(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);

    cam.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);

    // TODO: change the font of the random word

    font = new BitmapFont();
    font.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    word = new Word();
}

@Override
protected void handleInput() {

}

@Override
public void update(float dt) {
    handleInput();
}

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {

    // TODO: make it so it changes the next word that spawns

    // Check how much time has passed since a new word has been spawned
    // and create a new one if necessary
    if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - word.lastWordTime > 1000000000) {
        word.spawnWord();
    }

    Iterator<Rectangle> iter = word.words.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Rectangle word = iter.next();
        word.y -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); // move the words at a constant speed of 200 pixels/units per second

        // If the word reaches the bottom, remove it from the array
        if (word.y + 64 < 0) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

    batch.begin();
    for (Rectangle word1 : word.words) {
        font.draw(batch, word.getWordString(), word1.x, word1.y);
    }
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    font.dispose();
}
}
```

Word class:

```
public class Word {

public Array<Rectangle> words;
public long lastWordTime;

private FileHandle file, file2;
private BufferedReader reader, reader2;
private List<String> lines, lines2;
private String line, line2;
private Random random;
private String wordString;

public Word(){
    words = new Array<Rectangle>();
    spawnWord();
}

// Set the new Rectangle to a random position at the top of the screen
// and adds it to the words array
public void spawnWord() {
    Rectangle word = new Rectangle();
    word.x = MathUtils.random(0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - 64);
    word.y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    words.add(word);
    lastWordTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();

    // Read the file and put it into a list of strings
    file = Gdx.files.internal("words/wordsEn.txt");
    file2 = Gdx.files.internal("words/swearWords.txt");
    reader = new BufferedReader(file.reader());
    reader2 = new BufferedReader(file2.reader());
    lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    lines2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        line = reader.readLine();
        line2 = reader2.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (line != null && line2 != null){
        lines.add(line);
        lines2.add(line2);

        try {
            line = reader.readLine();
            line2 = reader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Choose a random string from the list
    random = new Random();
    wordString = lines.get(random.nextInt(lines.size()));

    // Filter out bad words
    if (lines2.contains(wordString)) {
        wordString = lines.get(random.nextInt(lines.size()));
    }
}

public String getWordString(){
    return wordString;
}
}
```

I think I narrowed it down to the render method in the PlayState class:

```
batch.begin();
    for (Rectangle word1 : word.words) {
        font.draw(batch, word.getWordString(), word1.x, word1.y);
    }
batch.end();
```

It gets the correct value from the method getWordString(), but it changes everything that has to do with the font on the screen instead of only the newly appeared word.

EDIT:

After trying to implement Sneh's example:

```
 public void spawnWord() {
    wordRectangle.word.x = MathUtils.random(0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - 64);
    wordRectangle.word.y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    words.add(wordRectangle.word);
    lastWordTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
```

I am getting an error on `words.add(wordRectangle.word)` that says "Rectangle can not be converted to WordRectangle". I think I am adding the wrong things.

Comment: word.getWordString() is a reference to the wordString. When you change wordString at one place, its reflected at every other place.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are updating your `wordString` variable which is referenced in your draw call. So when you update it's value it is reflected everywhere.

A fix for this will be to hold the rectangle and the word in a separate class.

```
public class WordRectangle {

    public String word;

    public Rectangle rectangle;

}
```

Now in your word class have a collection of above class and then add new objects to the collection when you spawn a new word.

Then in your render method

```
batch.begin();
    for (WordRectangle word1 : word.words) {
        font.draw(batch, word1.word, word1.rectangle.x, word1.rectangle.y);
    }
batch.end();
```

I would also suggest you to read [this](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/string-is-passed-by-reference-in-java/) useful article to clear things our for you.

Comment: I read the article and tried out your solution, but I am getting an error with the render method, that says that `WordRectangle` should be `Rectangle`. I don't fully understand what is going on though.

Comment: Yes because you may be trying to store rectange into a word rectangle. As I mentioned u will have to use Array<WordRectangle> and then add your rectangles and word inside and object of WordRectangle and then finally into the collection.

Comment: I left that part intentionally so that you can understand and try it yourself.

Comment: I'm completely lost. I made that object of WordRectangle and added that to the Array, but it gives me an error again. I appreciate it that you don't give the answer straight away, I prefer it that way! :D

Comment: I put an EDIT in my original post. It basically says "Rectangle can not be converted to WordRectangle", which I think has something to do with me adding the wrong things.

Comment: yes because you are trying to add a string inside a collection of WordRectangle.

Comment: I used word as the rectangle and wordString as the String, so I'm adding a rectangle in a WordRectangle (mixed up the names so that it's more in line with the other code, sorry for the confusion).

Comment: Sorry I can't help you like this. This is a different problem u have because you are not understanding the concept of data types.

Comment: I'll read some more stuff about it and then come back to your original answer. Thanks for the help though!